# gremlin - best step to be used as dummy for graphtraversal initialization

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, graph-traversal

Trying to build a graphtraversal dynamically, but i've a question on how to initialize the traversal with a dummy step. I'm using inject() as the dummy step, does anyone know if this will cause any harm or suggest a better step to be used as a dummy.

pseudocode:
fn setVertexProperties(properties):
final GraphTraversal<vertex, vertex> gt = __.inject();
foreach((k,v)-> gt.property(k,v));
end fn

thanks

Comment: I provided an answer below. Your pseudo code is a little confusing as the `property` step needs to be applied to a vertex. I'm happy to expand my answer if you can clarify a bit more your pseudo code. There are ways for example to seed a traversal with a map of vertices and properties which may be helpful depending on your exact use case.

Comment: First of all, love your book "Practical Gremlin" and recommends to anyone wanting to learn Gremlin. Regarding my question. Thanks @KelvinLawrence. Yes, only ID properties are added on addV(), rest are added separately using the function, so the question. 
this's the full  traversal :
 GraphTraversal tv = g.V().vertexfilterstep().fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV("label").property("idprop1",v1).property("idprop2", v2)); 
vertex v = tv.union(nonidpropertytraversal).next(); 
i'm writing a generic java function to add non-id properties that included simple, multi and meta properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building up a traversal dynamically in code then using `inject` is fine.

In more concrete terms something like this is commonly done:

```
t = g.inject(0)
t.addV('A')
t.addV('B')
t.iterate()
```

An `inject` step yields a `DefaultGraphTraversal` to which other steps can be added.

If you know your traversal will be doing a lot of, let's say, `addV` steps, then another way to go is to just do one `addV` to create the traversal object. As in:

```
t = g.addV('A')
t.addV('B')
t.addV('C')
t.iterate()
```